# bottom navigation bar is not showing correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

bottom navigation bar is not showing correctly, text under it is not showing and when icon is clicked, it don't change its color. please help, here is the xml file code.this is the file where fragments appear, i have added 5 items in bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".SplashActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem wasn't in XML code but was a in java activity code.

Thanks for helping :-)

Comment: This is not answer. You should delete the post since it can't help anyone and has no contribution to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

you can set color by :

```
    selectedTabColor="your_color"
```

Comment: color is setted in colors.xml

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".SplashActivity">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```